# How to find count of multiple records with different where conditions from same table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table such as this

```
ID    | cid   |lightness    | darkness     | color
------|-------|-------------|--------------|---------
1     | 5     |10           | 20           | green
2     | 5     |10           | 08           | green
3     | 5     |10           | 10           | green
4     | 5     |20           | 05           | green
5     | 8     |10           | 20           | red
6     | 8     |10           | 16           | red
7     | 8     |33           | 20           | red
8     | 5     |10           | 10           | green
```

I want to find out the following:

- Count of records where color has lightness 10
- Count of records where color has darkness 20

So the output should be

```
Color    | lightness   | darkness   | Total
---------|-------------|------------|---------
green    | 4           | 1          | 5
red      | 2           | 2          | 4
Total    | 6           | 3          | 9
```

I've tried the query below but it doesn't bring the correct results.

```
Select color, sum(lightness), sum(darkness)
from colortable
where cid in (5,8)
and (lightness = 10 or darkness = 20)
Group by color;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the following SQL as a new query, *qryBaseCounts*:

```
SELECT
    sub.color,
    sub.light_10,
    sub.dark_20,
    light_10+dark_20 AS light_plus_dark
FROM [
        SELECT
            color,
            Sum(IIf(lightness=10,1,0)) AS light_10,
            Sum(IIf(darkness=20,1,0)) AS dark_20
        FROM colortable
        WHERE
            cid In (5,8)
            AND (lightness=10
            OR darkness=20)
        GROUP BY color
    ]. AS sub;
```

Then you can use qryBaseCounts in a UNION query:

```
SELECT
    q1.color,
    q1.light_10 AS lightness,
    q1.dark_20 AS darkness,
    q1.light_plus_dark AS [Total]
FROM qryBaseCounts AS q1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    "Total",
    Sum(q2.light_10)
    Sum(q2.dark_20)
    Sum(q2.light_plus_dark)
FROM qryBaseCounts AS q2;
```

This is the Access 2007 output from that second query using your sample data for *colortable*:

```
color lightness darkness Total
green         4        1     5
red           2        2     4
Total         6        3     9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how the query can be modified to cope with if the color column is a multivalued field

Comment: I avoid multi-valued fields.  I suggest you create a new question which includes that requirement, and add a revised sample of input data.

Comment: I hate them as well, but I'm dealing with this god awful database that I've inherited. Will post a question. Thanks

Comment: I've posted the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902209/how-to-find-count-of-multiple-records-with-different-where-conditions-from-same
thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Select  color,
        sum(iif(lightness = 10, 1, 0)),
        sum(iif(darkness = 20, 1, 0)),
        count(*)
from    colortable
where   cid in (5,8)
Group by color;
```

This won't give you the totals row. Some SQL variants give a "WITH ROLLUP" clause or similar, but not Access AFAIK. You could use a union:

```
Select  color,
        sum(iif(lightness = 10, 1, 0)),
        sum(iif(darkness = 20, 1, 0)),
        count(*)
from    colortable
where   cid in (5,8)
Group by color

union

Select  'Totals',
        sum(iif(lightness = 10, 1, 0)),
        sum(iif(darkness = 20, 1, 0)),
        count(*)
from    colortable
where   cid in (5,8)
```

Comment: for total he can use count(*)

Comment: Sorry, was referring to the totals row, but I see from your comment I've missed a column (and failed to remove an unnecessary filter). Now rectified both. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. For totals row he can rerun the query without `group by color` part. But he will run two queryes

Comment: SQL is a generic tag The flavour of Access required is MS Access. Case is not available in MS Access.

Comment: @Remou - thanks, +1, while since I've worked with it (thank goodness). Have edited to what I think is now acceptable Access SQL...

Comment: @Mike Using your colortable sample data, the output from this one is: green, 4, 1, 5; red, 2, 2, 3; Totals, 6, 3, 8.  None of those rows match what you said you wanted.  How can this answer be correct?

Comment: @HansUp - my bad, had edited the 4 in the question to a 3 because I'd missed the bottom row of sample data. Not the OP's fault.

Comment: I'm testing with Access 2007 and not getting the correct answer. Sorry I had accepted the answer before as by looking at it, it made sense to me. but the number don't seem to be correct.