# How to find count of multiple records with different where conditions from same table with multivalued fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897178/how-to-find-count-of-multiple-records-with-different-where-conditions-from-same) earlier today but I have a follow up question to that which adds a complexity of multivalued fields.

Given a following table:

```
ID    lightness    | darkness     | color
------|-------------|--------------|---------
1     |10           | 20           | green, blue, yellow
2     |10           | 08           | green, purple, orange
3     |10           | 10           | black, magenta, orange
4     |20           | 05           | green, creame
5     |10           | 20           | red, purple
6     |10           | 16           | red, white
7     |33           | 20           | brown, red
8     |10           | 10           | green, blue
```

I want to find out:

- Count of records where color has lightness 10
- Count of records where color has darkness 20

So final output would be:

```
Color    | lightness   | darkness   | Total
---------|-------------|------------|---------
green    | 4           | 1          | 5
red      | 2           | 2          | 4
Total    | 6           | 3          | 9
```

The `group by` would lose its value and the results will be incorrect. The `.value` can be used on the multivalued field so I can do the following:
For Example:

```
select * from colortable where color.value = 2
```

Will show all records where green exists

```
select * from colortable where color.value = 3
```

Will show all records where red exists

I understand that this is really bad design but I've inherited this and have to run queries on the data.

Comment: Do you have any ability to change the design?  I guarantee you that you save yourself _far_ more headaches getting this properly normalized, than any 'space savings' leaving the table like this.  Also, 'Total' rows are best left to your reporting program, _not_ to the SQL engine itself

Comment: I am ok with not adding the Totals row. Regarding changing the design, I can but that will also involve changing the front end of the application used by people. So to answer your question, yeah I have access and intentions to change it but wanted to query and extract results out of the existing design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a multifield value column, your best solution is to make a new table and throw all the known colors in that table. So your new table would look like

```
ID | cid | color
---|-----|-------
1  | 2   | green
2  | 3   | red
```

Now you've got something to join with!

```
SELECT p.color, 
       Sum(IIf(lightness=10,1,0)) as lightness, 
       Sum(IIf(darkness=20,1,0)) as darkness,
       lightness+darkness AS Total
FROM colortable c inner join predefinedcolors p on p.id = c.color.value
WHERE c.color.value in (2,3)
GROUP BY c.color, p.conditionid.value
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are a known set of colours then you need to establish a table "KnownColors" for example.

```
SELECT ColourTable.ID, KnownColour, ColourTable.Lightness, ColourTable.Darkness,
ColourTable.Colour, ColourTable.Lightness, ColourTable.Darkness 
FROM ColourTable, knownColours WHERE (((ColourTable.Colour) Like "*" 
& [KnownColour] & "*") AND ((ColourTable.Lightness)=10) 
AND ((ColourTable.Darkness)=20));
```

will give you one row for each colour where lightness is 10 and darkness is 20

Answer (score 0):

you can get your result from your table use following,

```
--  ** Function for creating column from colors **

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(RTRIM(LTRIM(@slice)))       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end  
GO

-- ** Create view to get all colors in one column **

Create view [dbo].[vColors]
as
select distinct items from split(
(SELECT SUBSTRING(
 (SELECT ',' + color
FROM colortable
ORDER BY color
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV_Color),',')

GO

-- ** And Finally get the result from this query **

select items,sum(lightness)lightness,sum(darkness)darkness 
from colortable c inner join vcolors v on c.color like '%'+v.items+'%'
group by items

-- ** output is **

items   lightness   darkness
-------------------------------
black       10      10
blue        20      30
brown       33      20
creame      20      5
green       50      43
magenta     10      10
orange      20      18
purple      20      28
red         53      56
white       10      16
yellow      10      20
```

Comment: T-SQL does not work with MS Access, I was tempted to vote down, but perhaps you do not realize that SQL is a generic tag? There are quite a few different types of SQL and the particular type required here is Jet/ACE SQL as used in MS Access.